# How to solve simple optimization problem in R

Tags: r, optimization, minimization

I have three equations and I would like to solve for a parameter that minimizes the differences between them.

```
DifferenceA:   100/(1+d)^50 - 75/(1+d)^25
DifferenceB:   100/(1+d)^50 - 50/(1+d)^15
DifferenceC:   75/(1+d)^25 - 50/(1+d)^15
```

I would like to solve for the parameter d* that minimizes the sum of the squared residuals in the above differences preferably using R where:

[image]

I haven't done optimization in R and was wondering what packages and how to set-up solving a simple minimization problem like this in R?
thanks.

Comment: difference from what?  from each other?

Comment: I would like to solve for a single D* which minimizes the 3 differences {A,B,C}.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Any constraint on `d`?

Comment: No constraint in d.  The is essentially solving for an implicit discount rate if 100, 75, and 50 represent net present values of over time periods 50, 25, and 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a single-input objective function you can use `optimize()` (`optim()` is for R^n → R, i.e. a vector of parameters):

```r
fA <- function(d) 100/(1+d)^50 - 75/(1+d)^25
fB <- function(d)  100/(1+d)^50 - 50/(1+d)^15
fC <- function(d)   75/(1+d)^25 - 50/(1+d)^15

fn <- function(d) {
  vals <- c(fA(d), fB(d), fC(d))
  sum(vals^2)
}


optimize(fn, interval = c(-200, 2e5))
```

However, a quick graph (or some mathematical analysis I was too lazy to do) shows that all of these differences decrease to zero as `d → ∞` — so the answer will be infinite, or numerically equal to the upper bound of the interval you try (or wherever the gradient of the differences becomes so small that R gives up).

```r
curve(fA, from = 1e-5, to = 1e6, log="x")
curve(fB, add = TRUE, col = 2)
curve(fC, add = TRUE, col = 4)

curve(fA(x)^2, from = 1e-5, to = 1e6, log="xy")
curve(fB(x)^2, add = TRUE, col = 2)
curve(fC(x)^2, add = TRUE, col = 4)
```

[image: curves, log-x scale]

[image: same curves, log-log]

Comment: Thank you for the very useful example.  This certainly solves my original question on how to set this up and solve.  I think my issue now involves the problem definition.  When I solve any of the individual equations for d*, I get a value in the realm of what I would expect.  dmin* for fA = 0.04; dmin* for fB 0.05, etc.  I thought I could solve for a dmin* that accounted for all three simultaneously and summing the squared residuals seemed like a reasonable thing to do as a way to combine them into the problem. I was expecting to get something that better reflected the individual solutions.

Comment: @mpap, If you want to constrain the solution to lie within the range of the individual solutions then `mins <- sapply(list(fA, fB, fC), function(f) optimize(f, c(-200, 2e5))$minimum); optimize(fn, range(mins))`

Comment: You probably shouldn't be squaring the values of the differences. Summing them (or equivalently taking the mean) might be sensible - depending on what your actual goal is.